# Calculating a double pendulum

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

consider the following situation of a double pendulum.

[image: doppel pendulum]

We found the moving equations as
$$
\ddot{\theta_1}=-L_1\sin\theta_1 + \frac{m_2}{m_1}\cos\theta_2\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1),\\
\ddot{\theta}_2=-L_2\sin\theta_2.
$$
Respectively as a system (*)
$$
\dot{\theta}_1=w_1\\
\dot{\theta}_2=w_2\\
\dot{w}_1=-L_1\sin\theta_1+\frac{m_2}{m_1}\cos\theta_2\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)\\
\dot{w}_2=-L_2\sin\theta_2.
$$

Now the task is to find a first integral of the system (*).
As a hint it is said to find formula for the kinetic and potential energy of the system by working in cartesian coordinates.

I am stuydying mathematics and not physics... so I do not know how to determine kinetic and potential energy... can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kinetic energy is, in Cartesians,

$$\frac12 m_1 (\dot{x_1}^2 + \dot{y_1}^2) + \frac12 m_2 (\dot{x_2}^2 + \dot{y_2}^2) $$

where $(x_1,y_1)$ is the cartesian coordinates of the first bob, etc.  We find these velocities by differentiating the cartesian coordinates of the bob with respect to time.

I express these coordinates with respect to the rest positions of each bob.  The first bob is easy:

$$x_1 = L_1 \sin{\theta_1}$$
$$y_1 = L_1 (1-\cos{\theta_1}) $$

The position of the second bob, however, depends on the first (which is why the equations are coupled).  Specifically, I consider its rest position to be that along the line extended through the first pendulum.  Thus

$$x_2 = x_1 + L_2 \sin{(\theta_2-\theta_1)} $$
$$y_2 = y_1 + L_2 (1-\cos{(\theta_2-\theta_1)}) $$

Using these coordinates, the potential energy is simply $m_1 g y_1+ m_2 g y_2$.

Comment: What is the potential energy when using the coordinates $x_1=L_1\sin\theta_1, y_1=L_1\cos\theta_1, x_2=L_1\sin\theta_1+L_2\sin\theta_2, y_2=L_1\cos\theta_1+L_2\cos\theta_2$? What is the general formula for the potential energy?

Comment: It looks like you're still being targeted. I'll help you. +1.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey: much appreciated.