# Double pendulum lagrangian

Tags: dynamical-systems, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

[image]

could someone help me with the following problem, for part $b$  i know that $$\Bbb L=T-U$$ but i've forgotten how i can calculate the kinetic energy and potential energies

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825796/calculating-a-double-pendulum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you only need a hint. Let $r_{1},r_{2}$ be the positions of the particles. Then,
$$r_{1}=l(\sin\phi_{1},\cos\phi_{1})$$
$$r_{2}=l(\sin\phi_{1}+\sin\phi_{2},\cos\phi_{1}+\cos \phi_{2}) $$
It follows that $T=\frac{1}{2}m\|\dot{r}_{1}\|^{2}+\frac{1}{2}m\|\dot{r}_{2}\|^{2}$.

Another aproach is using complex numbers: $$r_{2}=l(e^{i\phi_{1}}+e^{i\phi_{2}})$$
Then, $\frac{1}{2}m\|\dot{r}_{2}\|^{2}=\frac{1}{2}m|il(\dot{\phi}_{1}e^{i\phi_{1}}+\dot{\phi_{2}}e^{i\phi_{2}}))|^{2}$, etc.

Comment: by $$||r||$$ are we referring to the mesh?

Comment: My problem wasnt finding the positions, it's the calculating of the v terms. would we substitute them in as a coordinate ?